# How to make multiple search and replace in files via bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, search, replace, while-loop

i have script. In this script i made search and replace of words. Word by word until word 'end'. It is ok and it works. You can see body of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

end=end   
until [ "$first" = "$end" ];do
    echo "please write first word";    
    read first   
    if grep -q "$first" *txt; then
        echo "word is exists"
        grep "$first" *txt
        echo "please write second word";    
        read second
        sed -i 's/'"$first"'/'"$second"'/g' *txt
    else
        echo "second word does not exists"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

It works for me. I have in the result console, where I can endlessly loop words, but if i want to do something like this: How can i write multiple words in line.

For example: "dog" "cat" "fish"

And search and replace all of these words. How can do it? For example, if i need to replace on these words ("elephat" "mouse" "bird"). How can you do it?
I mean search and replace words, like arguments.

Comment: You mean receiving the words to replace as arguments? Or read them from a file?

Comment: You have got to learn to indent.  I'm going to edit.  For the love of God, code in a readable way.

Comment: i mean receiving words like arguments

Answer (score 0):

Your English is rough, but I think you want to be able to prompt for multiple words, and replace them with a new set?

The below code will let you run a program like `replace_words one two three` and then be prompted for a list of words to replace, e.g. `1 2 3`.  After that, it exits.

```
declare -a replace_list=( "$@" )    # get the replace list as passed arguments
echo -n "Enter words to replace with: ";        read -ra sub_list
for ((i=0; i < "${#replace_list[@]}"; ++i)); do
    if grep -q "${replace_list[$i]}" *txt; then
        echo "first word is exists"
        sed -i "s/${replace_list[$i]}/${sub_list[$i]}/g" *txt
    else
        echo "${replace_list[$i]} does not exists"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a loop to process the arguments.

Assuming you run the script passing pairs of original replacement words (myscript.sh original_word1 replacement1 original_word2 replacement2 ...) it would be something like the following:

```
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
  original="$1"
  replacement="$2"

  # your code for actually replacing $original with $replacement

  shift   # discard already processed original arg
  shift   # discard already processed replacement arg
done
```

Note that if the user passes a last original word without replacement the script will just ignore it